# MvcContrib Grid sort on related object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I want to do server side sorting of a related table using MvcContrib Grid

I have

```
 @Html.Grid(Model.Result).Columns(column =>
{
    column.For(u => u.Name).Named("Name");
    column.For(u => u.Country.Name).Named("Country").SortColumnName("Country");
 }).Sort(Model.GridSortOptions)
```

This displays the table/grid correctly. However I cannot sort by Country.Name I get an error

**DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ended up doing a work around.

I added a new property to my ViewModel called "CountryName" which maps to Country.Name. This works fine.

So my code is now

```
 @Html.Grid(Model.Result).Columns(column =>
{
    column.For(u => u.Name).Named("Name");
    column.For(u => u.CountryName).Named("Country");
 })
```

And my ViewModel

```
public string Name {get; set;}
public Country Country {get; set;}
public string CountryName {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 2):

I [did some digging](http://groups.google.com/group/mvccontrib-discuss/browse_thread/thread/152e1a381c858b2e/bffe596470ae8b35?lnk=gst&q=hi+i+am+unable#bffe596470ae8b35) and it looks like the native OrderBy() method which MvcContrib Grid exposes does not support sorting data on a sub-property.

In the controller action which handles presenting and sorting the data, rather than calling `data = data.OrderBy(sort.Column, sort.Direction)`, you will need to customize the behavior slightly. In your case, the easiest solution would likely be to handle the value "Country.Name" specially, and then use the default behavior for the rest of the sortable columns. Something like this should suffice:

```
public ActionResult Index(GridSortOptions sort) {
  ViewData["sort"] = sort;
  var data = GetData();

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort.Column)) {
    if(sort.Column.Equals("Country.Name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        if(sort.Direction == SortDirection.Ascending) {
            data = data.OrderBy(d => d.Country.Name);
        } else {
            data = data.OrderByDescending(d => d.Country.Name);
        }
    } else {
        data = data.OrderBy(sort.Column, sort.Direction);
    }   
  }

  return View(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using "Country.Name" first, but that did not work, so I tried just Country and tried and setting the DataAnnotation [Key] on the name field. but still the same error

Comment: @Daveo Hmm, that's not what I would have expected! What happens if you omit the SortColumnName()? Does it try to sort on "Country" ?

Comment: If I do not add SortColumn name it just Tries to sort on "Name" which is the first column of the grid.  If I put SortColumnName like in your answer it says "Could not find a property called 'Country.Name' on type MyViewModel"

Comment: @Daveo I've updated my answer after doing a little more research.

Comment: @Nathan thanks for the effort but that seems like a lot of extra code and it seems more readable to do as I suggested in my answer to Flatten the View-model during the Select

Comment: @Daveo nothing wrong with that. If flattening is an option, I say flatten away.